# Selecting an item by its associated tables

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I'm working on building a recipe database. I'm trying  to build a query wehere I get all recipies that include a certain ingredient (such as onions, carrots), but I'm not how build my query. Essentally I'm trying to get a list of recipies that (given the proper amount of joins) have an Ingredient.name = 'onion'. My models are as follows:

```
ingredients = db.Table('ingredients',
    db.Column('modified_ingredient', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modified_ingredient.id')),
    db.Column('ingredient', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ingredient.id'))
    )

modifiers = db.Table('modifiers',
    db.Column('modified_ingredient', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modified_ingredient.id')),
    db.Column('modifier', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modifier.id'))
    )

modified_ingredients = db.Table('modified_ingredients',
    db.Column('recipe', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipe.id')),
    db.Column('modified_ingredient', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modified_ingredient.id'))
    )

class Recipe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(256))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    directions = db.Column(db.Text)
    prep_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    cook_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    image = db.Column(db.LargeBinary())
    ingredients = db.relationship('ModifiedIngredient', secondary=modified_ingredients)

class Ingredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ingredient'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, unique=True)

class Modifier(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'modifier'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, unique=True)

class ModifiedIngredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'modified_ingredient'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    unit = db.Column(db.String(20))
    ingredients = db.relationship('Ingredient', secondary=ingredients, 
        backref=db.backref('ingredients', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
    modifiers = db.relationship('Modifier', secondary=modifiers,
        backref=db.backref('modifiers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
```

It's mostly my inexperience with SQL and SQLAlchemy that is stumping me. I know that I'm joining something, but I'm not exactly sure how to phrase it in a way that works.

Comment: A little off-topic-- but it feels like your models are a little off. At the moment it's "One Recipe has many ModifiedIngredients, each ModifiedIngredient is made up of many  Ingredients and many Modifiers".  So I'd think the `ModifiedIngredient` should be a one-to-many relation to the `Ingredient` and `Modifier` rather than a many-to-many as it is now?  That would make the relations "One recipe has many ModifiedIngredients, each ModifiedIngredient is made up of one Modifier and one ingredient".

Comment: Well, an ingredient can have multiple modifications (stewed and diced tomatoes for example)

Comment: Sounds like you want to set up all possible items, so you can say 'Show me all tomatoes' and it'll show you canned, diced, crushed, whole etc, but not decaffeinated. But your relation between the `Recipe` and `ModifiedIngredient` means that you can't really do that. A 'Tomato Soup' recipe: it would want `ModifiedIngredient(amount=2, unit='Can', ingredients=[Ingredient(name='Canned Tomato')], modifiers=[Modifier('Crushed')])` which isn't transferable to a 'Bolognese' recipe that wanted just 1 diced can-- it would require a new `ModifiedIngredient` entry, multiple Modifiers on that wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option-1:** very tidy, but might not be the most efficient due to nested `EXISTS` clause:

```
q = (db.session.query(Recipe)
     .filter(Recipe.ingredients.any(
         ModifiedIngredient.ingredients.any(
             Ingredient.name == 'onion')
     )))
```

**Option-2:** should be faster, but if you query only certain columns (use `query(Recipe.name, ..)` instead of whole objects as below), you will end with with multiple results per each `Recipe` row because of `JOINs`:

```
q = (db.session.query(Recipe)
     .join(Recipe.ingredients)
     .join(Ingredient, ModifiedIngredient.ingredients)
     .filter(Ingredient.name == 'onion')
     )
```

Comment: I actually went with Option Two, I had figured it out a little before you posted this. How would I use this to get multiple ingredients though, as .filter(Ingredient.name == 'onion', Ingredient.name == 'tomato') didn't seem to be working

Comment: if you need `and` condition, you can just add another filter: `.filter(Ingredient.name == 'tomato')`. If you need `or`, then `.filter(or_(Ingredient.name == 'onion', Ingredient.name == 'tomato'))` would do it.